# How wordpress accesses its own database

Tags: database, wpdb

Hi I'm just curious as to how Wordpress accesses it's own database, meaning that when I look into an admin page like `link-manager.php` or `class-wp-list-table.php` I don't see any occurences of `$wpdb`.

So again, is there an internal way that Wordpress queries its own DB?

If so, could I use that type of function to call my own queries?

Answer (score 2):

WordPress uses only `$wpdb` to query db. This is the best practice to use `$wpdb` in WordPress. Read more about [wpdb](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/wpdb) class in codex.